# Is the number of conjugate always constant?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I confuse the definition of a conjugate.
In my text, definition of conjugation is following

$\mathbb{E}$ is an algebraic extension field of $\mathbb{F}$. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are conjugate over $\mathbb{F}$ if  irr($\alpha,\mathbb{F})$ = irr($\beta,\mathbb{F})$ for $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{E}$

With this definition, If $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathbb{\overline{F}}$ do not always have to be the same, Is the number of conjugate of  $\alpha \in \mathbb{E}$ different according to $\mathbb{E}$?

- $\mathbb{\overline{F}}$ is algebraically closed field of $\mathbb{F}$.
- irr($\alpha,\mathbb{F})$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}$

Comment: Do you mean "the number of conjugates of $\;\alpha\;$ **inside** $\;\Bbb E\;$ , or simply in some algebraically closed field containg $\;\Bbb E\;$ ?

Comment: I know, but I am confused. Please answer them correctly.

Comment: @Ed What does "I know" mean?? Answer my question, please.

Comment: They are the number of conjugate in each corresponding Filed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $x^3-2$.

Then its zeros are $a,ab,ab^2$, where $a=\sqrt[3]2$, $b^3=1$ and $b$ is complex number not real.

Conjugates of $a$ in $\mathbb Q(a)$ is only $a$.

Conjugates of $a$ in $\mathbb Q(a,b)$ are $a,ab,ab^2$.